# Try line still fire after an exception is thrown

Tags: php, laravel-4, try-catch

I'm trying to trouble shoot a try/throw/catch structure between two of my php files. I have die and dump lines in to narrow down where my errors are coming from, i.e. the `die(var_dump(...))` line is not normally there.

Here's my try/catch block:

```
public function sendWelcome(){
    try{

        $this->welcome->sendWelcomeforAllNewUsers();
        die(var_dump(["here", __FILE__ , __LINE__]));

    }catch(\Exception $exception){

        Session::flash('error', $exception->getMessage());
        return Redirect::to('main');

    }

    Session::flash('success', "Welcome emails have been sent");
    return Redirect::route('admin.importedAccounts');
}
```

And here's my method that could throw an exception:

```
protected function sendWelcomeToNewUsers(){

    if(empty($this->newUsers)){
        throw new \Exception('There are no new users to send welcome emails to.');
    }

    foreach($this->newUsers as $user){
        $this->sendWelcome($user->getLogin());
    }
}
```

I'm firing the block now knowing that `$this->newUsers` is empty (definitely evaluates as true), but I'm still hitting my die and dump line which is the next line in the try block.

I added a die and dump line to the if that throws the exception just to be sure it's firing:

```
    if(empty($this->newUsers)){
        die(var_dump(["here", __FILE__ , __LINE__]));
        // when I add this in and try it in the browser I definitely die here.
        throw new \Exception('There are no new users to send welcome emails to.');
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is there something that would allow a try to still fire even if an exception has been thrown?

Comment: Why are you calling `sendWelcomeforAllNewUsers()` but the method is named `sendWelcomeToNewUsers()`?  Doesn't instill confidence in the debugging.

Comment: **facepalm**. I have an different method in my WelcomeService class named  `sendWelcomeforAllNewUsers`. That method has a catch method in it which is causing the problem :/. That method shouldn't be there (it was part of the prototyping) so I can pull it out. Thanks for pointing that out. I was looking everywhere but at the method names.